# Screen size in Samsung Tablet 10.1

Tags: android, screen, ui-automation, samsung-mobile

I have rooted my Samsung Tablet 10.1 (Android 4.1.2) and used AutoMacro for auto touching. But AutoMacro gets the wrong screen size. The expected values are 1280 X 800, but the new values are 4096 X 4096. I have the same problem in other auto touching softwares.

I have reset my Tablet several times, but this problem still exists.

I use this command `getevent -p` to show this message:

```
add device 7: /dev/input/event1
  name:     "sec_touchscreen"
  events:
    ABS (0003): 002f  : value 0, min 0, max 9, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                0030  : value 0, min 0, max 255, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                0035  : value 0, min 0, max 4095, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                0036  : value 0, min 0, max 4095, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                0039  : value 0, min 0, max 65535, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                003a  : value 0, min 0, max 255, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                003c  : value 0, min 0, max 255, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                003d  : value 0, min 0, max 416, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
  input props:
    INPUT_PROP_DIRECT
```

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: well never root your device again Sir.

Comment: @Elltz, Why can't I root my device?

Comment: You can't change settings of AutoMacro somehow?

Comment: No I can't change anything.

Answer (score 8):

**Option 1:**

Check the device `build.prop` manually and verify if the densities are correct.

1. Goto `/system` using a file explorer and search for the file `build.prop`
2. Make a backup of the `build.prop` file
3. Open `build.prop` file and search for the key "`lcd_density`". My device has a screen density of 240 by default. You should have a different one. Just Increase or decrease until you get your desired result.
4. Finally set the file permission to `rw-r--r--`
5. Reboot and re-check.

Tips:

There are currently 7 different DPIs that Android supports natively:

```
120 (LDPI)
160 (MDPI)
213 (TVDPI)
240 (HDPI)
360 (XHDPI)
480 (XXHDPI)
640(XXXHDPI)
```

You can apply any densities between those scale.

**Option 2:**

Use [Window Manipulator](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/root-window-manipulator-t2846784?)

[image]

Hope that'll help!

Comment: Sorry for your suggestion. Your method is not working for me. Resolution doesn't change when I use any lcd_density value above.

Comment: I have updated into android 4.4.2, and have the same problem. I think this could be related with screen calibration.